# Como migrar um site sem perder o rankeamento do domínio

Tags: wordpress, seo

Um cliente tem um site bastante antigo em Wordpress e me contratatou para fazer melhorias no site: mudar tema, conteúdo das páginas, excluir algumas páginas e acrescentar novas.

Todas essas melhorias estou fazendo um ambiente desenvolvimento, para não tirar o site do ar como ele me pediu. A minha dúvida é: como posso fazer a migração do site para ambiente produção sem perder a relevância do domínio nas pesquisas?

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta, mas se for como mudar o domínio do site sem perder relevância e ranqueamento, inicialmente vai ter que manter o domínio antigo por algum tempo o usando apenas como ponto de redirecionamento para o novo domínio e fazer a evolução gradual do design.

Comment: Pesquise sobre redirecionamento 301 e 302